# OnActivity is executing twice in same activity

Tags: android, kotlin, facebook-android-sdk

I tried to run it several ways but callbackManager called twice and only at login. when I press fb_login_button again (for logout) it only executes once
. The toast is used to show it on screen  but they both show the same things(executed twice).

```
fb_login_button.setOnClickListener({
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, arrayListOf("public_profile","email"))
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult>{
                override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult?) {                    
Toast.makeText(this@SignIN,"Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    Log.d("ss",":'(")
                }

                override fun onCancel() {
                    Toast.makeText(this@SignIN,"Cancelled Facebook",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }

                override fun onError(error: FacebookException?) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@SignIN,"Error Facebook",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            })
    })
}    
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    callbackManager?.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

After searching alt I got a few posts regarding same issue but on different activities.
[onActivityResult executing twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26680814/onactivityresult-executing-twice)
[onViewCreated called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52001726/onviewcreated-called-twice)
[OnActivityResult getting called twice in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237366/onactivityresult-getting-called-twice-in-android)
[onActivityResult called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736724/onactivityresult-called-twice)

Comment: Hi. We lack of information here. Where is `fb_login_button.setOnClickListener()` called? What is "OnActivity" that gets called twice? Show us `SignIN` also please.

Comment: it is located in override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)

Comment: override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.sign_in)

fb_login_button.setOnClickListener({
            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()

Comment: SignIN is the activity name... this is the same activity in which these functions are written

Comment: I receive result code=-1 both times... it runs both times and log me in but why twice

Comment: @shkschneider is it enough?